# OctoberCMS global page properties?

Tags: php, laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

Is it possible to set a series of global properties (such as social media usernames) that are available to all page views in OctoberCMS rather than having them associated to one CMS page or Static Page at a time?

For example, being able to use `{{ twitter_username }}` in any template, but it wouldn't show up as a field  in  any page form on the backend.

**UPDATE:** this can be achieved by registering a Twig function using `registerMarkupTags` in your plugin:

```
use System\Classes\PluginBase;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function registerMarkupTags()
    {
        return [
            'functions' => [
                'globals' => function($var) {
                    switch ($var) {
                        case 'twitter_username':
                            return 'mytwitterusername';
                    }
                    return null;
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

In this case, calling `{{ globals('twitter_username') }}` from any template prints `mytwitterusername`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm yes better you need to add code to `life-cycle` method in `layouts`, so now `page` which are using `that layout` will have this info already loaded.

> In **layout code block** you can use something like this

```
use RainLab\Pages\Classes\Page as StaticPage;

function onStart() {    
    $pageName = 'static-test'; // this will be static page name/filename/title
    $staticPage = StaticPage::load($this->controller->getTheme(), $pageName);
    $this['my_title'] = $staticPage->viewBag['title'];
    $this['twitter_username'] = $staticPage->viewBag['twitter_username'];

}
```

now inside your `cms page` you can use this variable

```
<h1>{{ my_title }} </h1>
<h3>{{ twitter_username }} </h3>
```

let me know if it you find any issues

Comment: The site uses multiple layouts so it had to be done slightly differently to this but your code helped a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use theme config file which gives you more flexibility rather than hardcoding the values in to the code block.
https://octobercms.com/docs/themes/development#customization

Comment: It's not ideal for this particular site that the other admin has access to edit a theme's properties, but thank you for this.

Comment: but you can still adjust permissions for each admin